# What does "##" after variable mean?

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

`Js.coerce_opt (Dom_html.document##getElementById id)`

I'm new to OCaml, and I'm dealing with Js_of_Ocaml recently. I've seen code as above that includes two pounds after between variable and function. What do they mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ordinary method calls for OCaml objects are written as `obj#meth`.

In order to handle `Js` objects, `js_of_ocaml` adds a (ppx) syntax extension that uses `obj##meth` for invoking methods for `Js` objects: https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/4.0.0/manual/ppx .